# How do I create a custom theme, or layout using images?

Tags: theming

I would like to create a custom theme, for which I have the images for parts of the theme, such as header, footer, menu, logo. I don't understand how to start to create a layout. I have gone through "Themeing guide," but I don't know where to start.

Comment: This is a too broad question, similar to "How do I create a module?" Questions should be more scoped, as per [faq]: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: This is the best link I can provide you: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download a theme such as [AdaptiveTheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme)  or [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) as a base and then create a sub-theme.